# How to numerate drupal views rows in twig?

Tags: views, 8, theming

For css purpuses I want to add custom class name to the first item in view.

```
<article class="myclass"></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
```

I need the number in views-view-fields--viewname.html.twig to make some logic expression like

```
if(view-num == 1) {
    <article class="myclass"></article> 
} else { 
    <article></article>
}
```

or maybe in one of the variables I get in fields {{fields.view_number.content}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fields template is probably not the best place. Normally you would do this in the views style plugin. `Grid` has such options built in, for `Unformatted` you can add

```
loop.first ? 'views-row-first',
```

to  *views-view-unformatted.twig.html*:

```
{% if title %}
  <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
{% endif %}
{% for row in rows %}
  {%
    set row_classes = [
      default_row_class ? 'views-row',
      loop.first ? 'views-row-first',
    ]
  %}
  <div{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }}>
    {{ row.content }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: is there a way to add into the classes inside row.content? I have there <article class="breaking">
    <a href="{{fields.view_node.content}}">
  <img src="{{fields.field_image.content}}"> 
  <h2>{{fields.title.content}}</h2>
    </a>
    <p>{{fields.body.content}}</p>
</article>

Comment: I've replied to your [comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/262924/how-to-numerate-drupal-views-rows-in-twig/262933?noredirect=1#comment322030_262925), now you can remove first-child from the css `.views-row-first article {
  // some styles here only for first item
}`

Answer (score 0):

No need for Twig, just do it with CSS:

```
.name_of_your_view_parent_container article:first-child {
  // seome styles here only for first item
}
```

Comment: For some reason particulaly first-chid not working in all browsers. I had problems with it in chrome. So counting views number would be preferable